# how to configure default enum value in mongoose sub doc?

Tags: node.js

I am using mongodb along with mongoose js in my node js application . I created a mongoose document schema  called “CompanySchema” which is using “TeamSchema” (another mongoose document schema) as a sub document. Inside this “TeamSchema” it has an array defined as employees which is using “EmployeeSchema” (another mongoose document) as a subdocument. So my question is when I am trying to save the document “CompanySchema” the default value for requirement status “unmet” is not getting set. So can you guys explain me what I am doing wrong in here?

```
export var EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
 id: {
   type: String
 },
 requirement: {
   type: {
     status: {
       type: String,
       enum: ['met' 'unmet'],
       default : 'unmet'
     }
   },
   default: null
 },
});

export var TeamSchema = mongoose.model<TeamModel>("Team", new mongoose.Schema({
 id: {
   type: String,
 },
 name: {
   type: String
 },
 employees: [EmployeeSchema]
}));

export var CompanySchema = mongoose.model<CompanyModel>("Company", new mongoose.Schema({
 id: {
   type: String
 },
 team: TeamSchema.schema,
}));
```

Comment: There is only one field on requirement attribute. I am wondering why did you define another field 'status' and defined enum for it.

Comment: I want to add some other attributes inside the requirement attribute in the near future. but for now it only has the attribute status which is an enum. The default value of this attribute should be "unmet" and it will be updated into "met" at run time

Answer (score 5):

I think there is two problems in your schema.

First, you use the *Mongoose* reserved keyword `type`.

> By default, if you have an object with key 'type' in your schema,
>   mongoose will interpret it as a type declaration.

Mongoose doc: [typeKey](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#typeKey)

Second, you set a default value to `null`, which should give you an error if you had not used the `type` keyword as a property name. Try to rename `type` to `requirement_type` for exemple and you'll get this error:

```
TypeError: Invalid value for schema path `requirement.default`
```

Which is coherent since it precisely needs a type to set default value.

> SchemaType#default(val)
>   Sets a default value for this SchemaType.

Mongoose doc: [SchemaType-default](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-default)

I do not really understand why you want to make it `null` by default, but you can do it by adding for exemple a `Mixed type`:

```
requirement: {
   type: {},
   requirement_type: {
     status: {
       type: String,
       enum: ['met', 'unmet'],
       default : 'unmet'
     }
   },
   default: null
 }
 // => { requirement_type: null }
```

Or you can remove the default and you'll get:

```
requirement: {
   requirement_type: {
     status: {
       type: String,
       enum: ['met', 'unmet'],
       default : 'unmet'
     }
   }
 }
// => { requirement_type: { status: 'unmet' } }
```

Note: You must separate the enum values ​​with a comma.